# Choosing a right version of support library base on compileSDKversion

Tags: android, sdk, android-support-library

my `compileSDKversion` is 26, so i want to add some support libraries into the app `build.gradel` such as `implementation 'com.android.support:card-v7:26.x.x'`.
How do i choose the right version for my current `compileSDK version`?

I just did "try and fail". I mean, i type x=1 then running `"sync project with gradle"`, and wait for the IDE notifies it runs fine. But i don't know what exactly appropriate version i should use. I did search, i found some people tell the version of support library basing on `compileSDKversion`, and should use the last 'compileSDKVersion', but that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: I think I find I reference for you https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions. The last version for api 26 is `26.1.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup can help you to setup a `support librairy`.

I think in your case `card` is `cardview`. Because I don't find `card` when I try sync.

This is an exemple of what I suggest for sdk 26

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        targetSdkVersion 26
        ...
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    ...
}
```

Comment: I type wrong for `"card"`. Yeah, i must be `"cardview"`. Also, I think we should use the `lastest` of version support library corresponding to the `compileSDKversion`. And if you want to know what the lastest version is, you can see at the link: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions